# declaring an array of PictureBoxes

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception, picturebox

I am trying to declare an array(Boxes) of PictureBoxes and store the pictureboxes(Box1,Box2,....) that I created in the form 1 ; in the array. I put the code.

```
Dim Boxes() As PictureBox

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Boxes(0) = Box1
    Boxes(1) = Box2
    Boxes(2) = Box3
    Boxes(3) = Box4
    Boxes(4) = Box5
    Boxes(5) = Box6
    Boxes(6) = Box7
    Boxes(7) = Box8
    Boxes(8) = Box9
End Sub
```

But there shows an error of null reference error. How to solve the error. Please help me. Note that {box1, box2, box3} are all PictureBox and I have created all the nine pictureboxes(box1, box2, box3......) in the form.

Comment: Change this `Dim Boxes() As PictureBox` in `Dim Boxes(9) As PictureBox`

Comment: Change the array in a `List(Of PictureBox)` and just add elements to it: `Private Boxes As New List(Of PictureBox)`, then `Boxes.AddRange({Box1, Box2, ...})`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error because you declare the array but not the length of the array.

Change this :

> Dim Boxes() As PictureBox

To :

```
  Private Boxes(9) As PictureBox
```

---

Maybe you can use a list instead of an array :

```
Private Boxes As List(Of PictureBox) = New List(Of PictureBox)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Boxes.Add(Box1)
    Boxes.Add(Box2)
    Boxes.Add(Box3)
    Boxes.Add(Box4)
    Boxes.Add(Box5)
    Boxes.Add(Box6)
    Boxes.Add(Box7)
    Boxes.Add(Box8)
    Boxes.Add(Box9)
End Sub
```

With a list, you dont have to care about the length.

Comment: This will still lead to an NRE because `Boxes` is never instantiated